# How do I remove <br> tags from a StringBuilder in Java?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Just it, I know how to do it with a string but not with a StringBuilder.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't remove `<br>` (or something else) from a string, strings are immutable. You can create a new string, that is like the original without the tags (or something else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `indexOf()` to locate the tags, and `delete()` to remove them.

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

To do this efficiently you would need to use `indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` in a loop to ensure you removed multiple tags - and be careful how you update `fromIndex` after removing a tag! The simpler but inefficient way would be to just call `indexOf()` repeatedly until you run out of matches, but this would keep restarting the search from the start of the String.

Or you could convert the StringBuilder to a String, create a new String with the tags removed using `replaceAll()`, then create a new StringBuilder with the result. Although this initially seems unnecessarily ugly and inefficient, it's probably less code, and clearer to read, if efficiency is not a priority.